# How can I set a file name using a variable in a Visual Studio project template

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsx, visual-studio-templates

I have a VS 2013 project template with a item like below

```
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Target.xml">Target.xml</ProjectItem>
```

What I want is "Target.xml" to be MyProjectName.xml.

I know I can use variables inside the file but not in the name.

Thanks

G

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, you can also use variables within the item template. 
For instance...

```
<ProjectItem 
    TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.xml" 
    ReplaceParameters="true" 
    ItemType="Content">Target.xml</ProjectItem>
```

...whereby `fileinputname` is the name as specified in the wizard (without extension). The `safeprojectname` parameter would give you the project name (not sure, if this can only be used in conjunction with a project template, rather than in an isolated item template).

This is the link to the `Project and Item Templates` documentation; might be of your interest: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx

A list of available parameters can be found at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx

Comment: it seems TargetFileName property does not work properly, when it is set VS is not able to copy the file. i tried it for a C# project template  wiht VS 2015.

Comment: @tutalia I updated the links to the documentation; since the content relates to Visual Studio 2015 and earlier versions, it may have changed for Visual Studio 2017, but I am not sure... The parameters might be case-sensitive.

Comment: for future readers, if the file is referenced in the proj file, don't forget to change the references inside the proj file as well. (ie <None Include="%projectname%.config" />)

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft documentation doesn't mention that you also have to modify the .proj file.

```
<Content Include="Target.html" />
```

change to

```
<Content Include="$projectname$.html" />
```

Also, in the .vstemplate file, the ReplaceParameters attribute doesn't need to be changed to "true" if you're just changing the filename.