# Set file name as project name in VS template

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-templates

I've been trying to make my own template in VS for C++.
I want to have a `cpp` and `hpp` file with the same name as the project.
I have already read this link: [How can I set a file name using a variable in a Visual Studio project template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036809/how-can-i-set-a-file-name-using-a-variable-in-a-visual-studio-project-template)

Howerer, when using my template, the files are not in the project that I've created.

Here is my `vstemplate` file:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>My Template</Name>
    <Description>A test template</Description>
    <ProjectType>VC</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>MyProject</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.png</Icon>
    <PreviewImage>__PreviewImage.png</PreviewImage>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="MyTemplate.vcxproj" File="MyTemplate.vcxproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$.vcxproj.filters">MyTemplate.vcxproj.filters</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$.cpp">MyFile.cpp</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$.hpp">MyFile.hpp</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Managed to figure it out, had to replace file names in `vcxproj` file itself. Thanks for helping!

Comment: `Project TargetFileName="MyTemplate.vcxproj"`->`Project TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$.vcxproj"`?
And do you have the template files in the root directory of the template zip file? VS copies and renames the files, it doesn't create files out of nothing.

Comment: Yes, of course I have the files there. I tried also using $safeprojectname$.vcxproj but then the solution is completely empty, with not even a vcxproj file in it.

Comment: Managed to figure it out, had to replace file names in ```vcxproj``` file itself. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Would you share what your changes to project file were?

Comment: @user3461121 I added an answer explaining what I did. I really should have done that way earlier, very sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up succeeding using the following method:

- I added two files to my template, named `$safeprojectname$.hpp` and `$safeprojectname$.cpp`.
- I edited my `vcxproj` file (using notepad++, or any other text editor for that matter), adding the following tags inside of the main `Project` tag:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="%24safeprojectname%24.hpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="%24safeprojectname%24.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I had to use `%24` as `$` is not a valid character in this context, and `24` is the ASCII (/unicode) value of that character.

Comment: I could get away with '$'. Thanks for answer to question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method:

1. Edit template file:

```xml
<ProjectItem 
  ReplaceParameters="false" 
  OpenInEditor="true" 
  TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$.cpp"
>
  task.cpp
</ProjectItem>
```

Replace the filename, not including the extension, with `$safeprojectname$`.

2. Edit vcxproj file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ClCompile Include="$(RootNamespace).cpp" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Find the `<ItemGroup>` section with the file name and replace it, not including the extension, with `$(RootNamespace)`.

File `task.vcxproj.filters` may be deleted.